# Admob loadAd doesn't load the ad until visiting another activity

Tags: android, admob

I'm having a weird problem with Admob: I have two activity #1 and #2, each has an Adview.
I called adView.loadAd in onCreate of each activity. However, it seems that the loadAd call in activity #1 doesn't actually start until I visit activity #2 (I put a hook in adViewListener's onReceiveAd, and whenever I visit activity #2, then the onReceiveAd for adView #1 is called). What did I do wrong ?

Sequence of events:

```
Create adView #2
Loading ad for #2
(I wait here and no ads show up on the first activity, so I launch the 2nd activity at this point)
Create adView #3
Loading ad for #3
Got ad for #3
Got ad for #2
(Now if I press back to the first activity, I could see the ad shown up immediate because it is already loaded).
```

I'm using admob 6.4.1.

My adview code is just like what the official tutorial said

```
adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, _adBannerID);
container.addView(adView);
final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

More information:
I found that the difference in the request that gets no ads served is this part:

"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0}

Comment: Can you please your ADView Code ? which you have used in activity to load the aDS

Comment: Please put your actual code here.

Comment: You get the same problem when you use the test banner?

Comment: Yes, I got the same problem with test banners

Comment: Is your AdView construction code identical in both Activities? Are you executing that code in Activity#onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

Ads do not run immediately after launching the application. It would take a couple of seconds to show,
 make some changes to your code , may it works.

```
adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, _adBannerID);
container.addView(adView);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(false);
adView.loadAd(request);
```